# How can we checkout a specific revsion of a file in perforce?

Tags: perforce

I want to checkout an older specific version from the command line, How can I do that ? couldn't find any help in documentation in p4 docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "checkout" isn't standard terminology in Perforce; if you're coming from git then what you call "checkout" is "sync" (and also "revert" and "switch" because of how badly "git checkout" is overloaded), but "checkout" is also sometimes used to refer to "opening" a file in Perforce, which is sort of like "staging" in git but not exactly.

I'll describe how to both "sync" and "open" a file and you can figure out which operation corresponds to whatever you're trying to do.

---

To **sync** a file from the depot into your workspace, use the `p4 sync` command:

```
p4 sync FILE#VERSION
```

If no `VERSION` is specified, the default is `#head` (the latest).  If no `FILE` is specified, the entire workspace is synced.

After a file is **synced**, it is read-only in your workspace; you can view the file, build, test, etc, but the file itself may not be modified until it's **opened**.

To **open** a file for edit (so that you can make changes to it and then submit those changes to the depot), use the `p4 edit` command:

```
p4 edit FILE
```

Whatever version has been **synced** to your workspace is the one that is **opened for edit** by this command.  If you want to `submit` your change, you will need to `resolve` the later changes first, but you have the option when resolving of discarding those changes.  (If your primary intent is to discard specific changes, you can do this more directly with the `undo` command.)

You can view currently-synced files with the `p4 have` command, and currently-open files with the `p4 opened` command.

Comment: will that sync to default changelist ?

Comment: There is no such thing as **sync**ing to the default changelist.  When you **open** a file, it goes into a pending changelist in your workspace; if no numbered changelist is specified, then it goes into the "default changelist" (which is really just a name for all your open files that aren't in a changelist yet).

Comment: i have a file on depot I am trying to view files by double clicking they are pulled and opened. I want to do the same thing from commandline.

Comment: Just `p4 sync` the file and then view it in whatever editor you like.  You do not need to **open** the file in a changelist if all you want to do is view it (an **open** file in Perforce is specifically "open for write"; it's not the same as opening something in an editor to view it).

Comment: e.g. `p4 sync FILE` ; `notepad FILE`

Comment: I get error saying `Path'file/path'  is not under client's root '~/home/zhang/zhang_host12'`

Comment: You need to provide a valid path to the actual file; Perforce can't figure out what file you're trying to sync if you just give it a random string.  :)  Either `cd` into your client root (as indicated by the error message) and provide a path relative to that local directory, or provide the full depot path (e.g. `//depot/file/path` or whatever).

Comment: If `zhang_host12` doesn't look like the right client root (i.e. the one you see in P4V on the same client machine), you may be using the wrong client spec; look at your "workspace" in P4V (this is the name of your client spec) and then do `p4 set P4CLIENT=your_workspace_name` at the command line to match it.